# Antimatter and quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, schroedinger-equation, antimatter, dirac-equation

This question could have a very simple answer but I could not find that answer anywhere. My question is since electrons, protons, etc they all have their antiparticles, why are not they mentioned in Quantum Physics? And if they are real, should not they be included into Schrödinger equation?

Comment: They’re in the Dirac equation, and in all quantum field theories. They can only be understood when using *relativistic* quantum mechanics.

Comment: They are mentioned and appear in UV completions of the Schrödinger equation such as the Dirac equation. The reason you may have not seen this is that this is  part of a subject called Quantum Field theory which goes beyond non-relativistic quantum mechanics.

Comment: because of asymmetry between matter and antimatter we have not observed them in usual low energy experiments. But at high energy quantum field theory is relevant than quantum mechanics and we should consider antiparticles.

Comment: The 1S-2S transition in antihydrogen is experimentally the same as the 1S-2S transition in hydrogen. Seems like the quantum mechanics of the two are the same.

Comment: Antihydrogen is approximated by the Schrodinger equation to the same accuracy as hydrogen is.

Comment: My first comment meant that the relationship between particles and antiparticles can only be understood with relativistic QM. The non-relativistic behavior of antiparticles can be understood with the Schrodinger equation.

Comment: It's entirely unclear to me what you mean with antimatter being "not mentioned in Quantum Physics".

Comment: @ACuriousMind My guess is that the OP means that antiparticles were not mentioned in their intro QM course.

Comment: Yes. Its not mentioned in our Quantum mechanics course. I just try to understand. For example, does not positrons have any effects on electron correlation?

Comment: Yes, virtual electrons and positrons slightly change how electrons interact with protons and with other electrons. QED includes this small effect. The Schrodinger equation does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The non-relativistic behavior of antiparticles can be understood with the Schrodinger equation. For example, anti-hydrogen is approximated by the Schrodinger equation to the same accuracy as hydrogen is. This is often never mentioned in an introductory Quantum Mechanics course.

But the *relationship* between particles and antiparticles can only be understood using *relativistic* quantum mechanics, such as the Dirac equation or relativistic quantum field theory. Quantum electrodynamics (QED) is an example of the latter and explains, among many other things, how an electron and a positron can annihilate into photons.

Since charged particles and their antiparticles can annihilate to produce photons, which are never non-relativistic, the non-relativistic Schrodinger equation cannot explain this interaction. Also, the Schrodinger equation cannot represent particles or antiparticles appearing or disappearing, like QED can. But the Schrodinger equation can explain how an anti-proton binds with an anti-electron (positron) to make anti-hydrogen, since this does not involve relativistic processes and no particles appear or disappear.

Comment: "can annihilate"  I would add "i.e. all quantum numbers become zero" and  after "to produce photons"  ", for low energies,and also particle antiparticle pairs for high energies" .

Comment: @annav Good points. Thanks.